# Fiddler can't get captures of Sharepoint 2013 & windows authentication site opened in Safari

Tags: sharepoint, safari, request, windows-authentication, fiddler

I can not see any request in fiddler when I open my site in safari. I see requests when open other sites. exp : google

My site is sharepoint 2013 site and I use windows authentication - NTLM.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the ancient/unsupported version of Safari on Windows? If so, that browser was hardcoded to bypass proxies for the Intranet zone (e.g. dotless URLs).

You can probably workaround this problem by using a fully-qualified domain name for your site (e.g. http://mysharepoint.myco.com) or by using a "fake" hostname (containing dots) that you re-map to the real hostname using the Tools > HOSTS feature inside Fiddler.

Comment: Hi Eric.I use Safari for windows version is 5.1.7. It is the newest version for windows. I tried to write to fiddler host file "test test.t.com". when I call test.t.com in any browser it opens a page with IIS 8 image.

Comment: @CIAODO: You haven't really specified what behavior you expect; what would you see if you visit "http://test" directly?

Comment: When I visit "test" it opens the same page with iis image and no trafic in fiddler. Maybe there is something to set in fissler to see proxies?.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Fiddler chains to the system's default upstream proxy on startup.

Comment: When I open my site in chrome and ie I saw traffic in fiddler. But, I can not see any traffic in fiddler when I open my site in safari (v5.1.7 for windows).

Comment: Safari doesn't send requests for intranet sites ("dotless hostnames") to any proxy (including Fiddler). To workaround that, you must use a dotted hostname / e.g. the Fully-qualified domain name.